# Replacing "<" and ">" in a string in PHP

Tags: php

I am looking to create a link which prints out the source code and I don't know why replacing the tags ("<" and ">") won't work and if there's a solution to this problem.

```
<?php
    $key = "";
    if(isset($_REQUEST["key"])){
    $key = $_REQUEST["key"];
}

$code = '

<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        h1 {
            text-align: center;
        }
        h4 {
            text-align: left;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="?key=y"> <h1> Source code </h1> </a>
    </body>
</html>

    ';

    echo($code);

    if($key == "y"){
        str_replace("<", "&#60;", $code);
        str_replace(">", "&#62;", $code);
        echo("<h4>" . $code . "</h4>");
    }
?>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Tried [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As commented Thamaizhan said already, you should use [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) instead of manually replacing those two characters.
2. Ignoring #1, your specific problem is caused by not assigning the result of `str_replace` anywhere. You would need `$code = str_replace(......, $code);`.

Comment: Yeah I was just being stupid and missed that part, but I'll gladlky look into "htmlentites". Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

You dont save result of str_replace function

```
if($key == "y"){
    $code = str_replace(["<", ">"], ["&#60;", "&#62;"], $code);
}
```

Comment: I'm bad at this am I not.

Comment: I prefer &lt; and &gt; entities

Comment: change 2nd argument to` ['&lt;', '&gt;']`

Answer (score 0):

```
$code = str_replace("<", "&lt;", $code);
$code = str_replace(">", "&gt;", $code);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if($key == "y"){
        echo("<h4>" . htmlspecialchars($code) . "</h4>");        
    }
```